# How can I select different Authentication Handlers in ASP.NET 6 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

I am trying to create an app on the top of ASP.NET 6/Core framework using C#. I want to allow users to login either using basic-authentication "app managed username and password" or LDAP authentication.

### Use Cases

**Scenario #1** a user that belongs to active directory would provide their username and password. `LdapAuthenticationHandler` would check the provided credentials against an LDAP server.

**Scenario #2** a user that does NOT belong to active directory would provide their username and password. `BasicAuthenticationHandler` would check the provided credentials against the username and password stored in the app's database.

### Findings

ASP.NET Identity allow me to register different types of authentication providers as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Also, it explains how to select the authentication provider using the `[Authorize]` attribute.

### Questions

When a user logins using the login form, how can I determine which authentication provider I should use to validate the user?

Comment: How about writing a custom authorization or claim transformer which checks both providers? Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203200/using-multiple-authentication-providers-in-c-sharp-net-core

Comment: take a look here as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Did you find a solution? Do you refer "app managed username and password" as built-in .Net Core Identity solution (auth scheme called `Identity.Application`)? If so, I have the same problem. All tutorials are about combining external auth providers only or adding them as external, meaning users from external provider should match with Identity database. It seems no simple solution is available for mixed auth Identity+External. I found when the Identity is enabled (`services.AddIdentity`) it intercepts many calls. External providers stop working normally and the whole workflow becomes a mess.